# U.S. OUT of MY BODY

Tags: phrase-meaning

> NYTimes runs a headline titled "As G.O.P. Fights Mask and Vaccine Mandates, Florida Takes the Lead". In the article, there is a picture in which one man holds a placard on his shoulder that reads: U.S. OUT of MY BODY. The original image's address is [here](https://static01.nyt.com/images/2021/11/17/us/17virus-florida-1/17virus-florida-1-threeByTwoMediumAt2X-v2.jpg?format=pjpg&quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale)

[image]

What does "U.S. OUT of MY BODY" mean? Does it mean "US is made of my body"?

Comment: Filling in some words: "[The] US [government should stay] out of my body." The protester's opinion seems to be that vaccines are an invasive procedure that should not be mandated by the government.

Comment: I read it as either "US, [get] out of my body!" or "[Get the] US [government] out of my body", but it amounts to the same thing. (Sometimes you might hear someone shout "Out of my way!", i.e. "Get out of my way", or British political campaigners might chant "Tories out!", i.e. "get the Tories out [of power/office/government]".

Answer (score 3):

I guess the man wants to express his opinion that the United States should **get out** (or keep out) of his body.
USA is metaphorically personified by a vaccine trying to enter his mortal frame.

Comment: But the virus he gets and then coughs out might enter _my_ body. His 'freedom' is my pine overcoat.